# Angular Material Datepicker input/change does not update reactive form control value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to use material datepickers within a reactive form, and I'm having issues due to the fact that changing the value of the input which is connected to the datepicker doesn't update the value of the form control.

As a result, this causes various issues, such as incorrect validation errors, like the required error showing despite the input being populated, and the form not being classed at valid, meaning buttons are not enabled when they should be.

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm">

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">

    <mat-label>Date</mat-label>

    <input matInput formControlName="date" [matDatepicker]="selectDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">

    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="selectDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>

    <mat-datepicker #selectDate></mat-datepicker>

    <mat-error *ngIf="form.date.errors.required">Date is required</mat-error>

    <mat-error *ngIf="form.date.errors.validDate">Invalid date</mat-error>

  </mat-form-field>


  <button mat-raised-button (click)="saveInvoice()" [disabled]="!invoiceForm.valid || !items.length">Save</button>

</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatDatepickerInputEvent } from '@angular/material';
import * as moment from 'moment';

import { DataService } from '@app/services/data/data.service';
import { ContactsService } from '@app/services/contacts/contacts.service';

// import { NewContactDialogComponent } from './dialogs/new-contact-dialog/new-contact-dialog.component';
import { NewItemDialogComponent } from '@app/invoices/dialogs/new-item-dialog/new-item-dialog.component';

import Invoice from '@app/interfaces/invoice.interface';
import InvoiceItem from '@app/interfaces/invoiceItem.interface';

import ValidateDate from '@app/validators/date.validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-invoice',
  templateUrl: './new-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-invoice.component.scss']
})

export class NewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {

  invoice: Invoice;
  invoiceForm: FormGroup;
  items: InvoiceItem[];

  constructor(public data: DataService, public contactsService: ContactsService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.items = [];

    this.invoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: ['', Validators.required],
        reference: ['', Validators.required],
        contactId: ['', Validators.required],
        date: [
            '',
            [
                Validators.required,
                ValidateDate
            ]
        ],
        saleDate: [
            '',
            Validators.required,
            ValidateDate
        ],
        dueDate: [
            '',
            Validators.required,
            ValidateDate
        ]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using

```
<input matInput [formControl]="date" [matDatepicker]="selectDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
```

Comment: Returns the following error in the console: "ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute". I think this is the old method of defining form controls

Comment: Can you share your code on stackblitz?
Meanwhile, you can try for setting the value on dateChange event of datepicker.